# How to find the latest file in a directory with Python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

```
def new_report(test_report):
    lists = os.listdir(test_report)                                   
    print(list)
    lists.sort(key=lambda fn:os.path.getmtime(test_report + "\\" + fn)) 
    file_new = os.path.join(test_report,lists[-1])        
    print(file_new)
    return file_new
if __name__=="__main__":
    test_report="path"
    new_report(test_report)
```

This is a code I found online. It is used to get the latest file in a directory, but I cannot understand this part:

```
 lists.sort(key=lambda fn:os.path.getmtime(test_report + "\\" + fn))
```

What is   `test_report+"\\"+fn ,why +fn`

Comment: This is a lambda function where it'll sort the contents of the file name list based on the key, the lambda function. So, each element in the list, will be `fn` argument to the lambda function. The lambda function will set the mtime to the file and sort the files based on this mtime.

Comment: In case this makes things clearer, `fn` stands for file name in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a bug, or at least an omission, in the program code you grabbed.  `os.path.getmtime` takes a full path to a file, so the lambda is trying to build a full path to thefile `fn` within directory `test_report`, but it's joining them with a nonstandard, OS specific delimiter `\\`.

Instead of hard coding a specific delimiter, it's best to let python come up with the delimiter appropriate for your operating system with,

```
os.path.join(report_dir, fn)
```

which would work on any operating system that Python supports.  Actually I see that `os.path.join` was used below.  I don't know why it wouldn't have been used above as well.

Further the program sets `lists` to something and then prints `list` which is valid, but only prints the `list` type.  Probably they meant to `print(lists)`

```
$ python -c 'print(list)'
<type 'list'>
```

Those changes together leave us with a final code that looks like this:

```
import os
def new_report(test_report):
    lists = os.listdir(test_report)                                   
    print(lists)
    lists.sort(key=lambda fn:os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(test_report, fn)))
    file_new = os.path.join(test_report,lists[-1])
    print(file_new)
    return file_new
if __name__=="__main__":
    test_report="/tmp"
    new_report(test_report)
```

I changed to '/tmp' so I could get actual results, which yielded this for me on my mac:

```
$ python t.py
['powerlog', 't', 'com.apple.launchd.pFf62wnsYV', 'com.apple.launchd.bAXuv2WS1L']
/tmp/powerlog
```

Note that the code I wrote works as-is.  This is what might be called a [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because it runs as coded.  It's always best practice to come up with a runnable piece of code for your questions!  In this case you did, because you posted the code you were asking about.  I just wanted to throw that in there because I see you're a new contributor, and it's probably the #1 missing piece of new contributors' questions that makes them hard to answer or difficult to confidently analyze.

Comment: i really appreciate your reply .  and i will take your suggestion in mind .I am   a new  contributors and also a new user of python  .here comes another question . i know os.path.join()  can combine multiple paths into one   , but why os.path.join(test_report,fn) can represent the full name of the file , i know test_report is the directory of the file , why fn is the name of the file . thanks

Comment: Lists.sort is being passed a lambda whose argument is each of the file names from listdir.  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function should make it clear.